# Vue2 project throwing error when installing Mqtt 4.3.7

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, mqtt

I am trying to install mqtt in a vue2 project through npm. However, it keeps throwing the following error:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (118:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|               if (alias) {
|                 packet.topic = ''
|                 packet.properties = { ...(packet.properties), topicAlias: alias }
|                 debug('applyTopicAlias :: auto assign(use) topic: %s - alias: %d', topic, alias)
|               } else {

 @ ./node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js 3:19-39
```

I examined ./node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js to make sure that there were not non-printable Unicode characters that could be creating this problem, but there were none. I have also tried downgrading to previous mqtt versions such as 2.18.9, 4.2.2 and 4.3.0, but the application enters an infinite loading loop.
From the error, I can infer that webpack could be the root cause in this issue since it is asking to add an appropriate loader, but I am a little lost with that. Could someone give me some insight on how to add this loader to the webpack.config.js? Or if there is a better way to solve this?

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobile-attendant",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  ,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --host localhost --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "copy-fonts": "cpy node_modules/framework7-icons/fonts/*.* src/fonts && cpy node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/*.{eot,ttf,woff,woff2} src/fonts",
    "postinstall": "npm run copy-fonts"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "framework7": "2.3.1",
    "framework7-icons": "0.8.9",
    "framework7-vue": "2.3.0",
    "material-design-icons": "3.0.1",
    "mqtt": "^4.3.7",
    "simple-keyboard": "2.29.47",
    "vue": "2.5.21",
    "vue-i18n": "8.21.1",
    "vue-resource": "1.5.1",
    "webpack-war-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "8.0.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.6.0",
    "cpy-cli": "1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "node-notifier": "5.3.0",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "ora": "1.4.0",
    "portfinder": "1.0.20",
    "postcss-import": "11.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.1.6",
    "postcss-url": "7.3.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "semver": "5.6.0",
    "shelljs": "0.7.8",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.3.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "vue-loader": "13.7.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "3.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.21",
    "webpack": "3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

And this is the webpack.config.dev.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const path = require('path');

function resolvePath(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    './src/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: resolvePath('www'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolvePath('src'),
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    contentBase: '/www/',
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolvePath('src'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7-vue'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/template7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/dom7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/ssr-window'),
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'stylus-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'images/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'app.css'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: resolvePath('static'),
      to: resolvePath('www/static'),
    }]),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar issue reported on the project's GitHub.  The only [comment](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1513#issuecomment-1220284880) suggesting a solution (written in Chinese) says they found success after downgrading to mqtt v4.2.7. The comment (google translated) says:

> I solved it. The relevant plugins I installed automatically installed
> the 4.3.7 version of mqtt. I deleted the mqtt folder in node_modules
> and reinstalled mqtt@4.2.7

Another possible option is [Vue-Mqtt](https://github.com/nik-zp/Vue-Mqtt) which looks to be a Vue specific implementation/wrapper of mqtt

Comment: Thx, i could not fix this problem and ended up using Vue-mqtt